# Compare if Date between

Tags: android

I want to find out whether Today is between two other Days:

```js
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd");
                    Date Start = sdf.parse("01-01");
                    Date Heute = sdf.format(Date());

                    if(Start.compareTo(Heute)>0){
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Date1 is after Date2: "+Heute, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }else if(Start.compareTo(Heute)<0){
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Date1 is before Date2: "+Heute+" & ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

But this is not possible:

```
Date Heute = sdf.format(Date());
```

Comment: you can check date.before(date) and date.after()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

format is to do Date->String. you need:

```
Date Heute = new Date();
```

Besides that I think that Start is 1st Jan, so `Start.compareTo(Heute)>0` will always be false

Comment: Thank you, Thats the way i need. 
I have think that i make the Date() also Format before.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do this:

```
Date Heute = new Date();
```

The simple date formatter is creating a date out of strings.